# How can I give an alias to a table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, table-alias

Why can't I give an alias to a table in Oracle DB? I tried to write a statement like this one:

```
select count(id) from users as usr where usr.dept = "SVC";
```

But Oracle threw me an error. I don't remember having problem when I use something like this in MySQL.

How can I give an alias to a table in Oracle?

Comment: What was the error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle doesn't allow `as` for table aliases, only column aliases.  So do:

```
select count(id)
from users usr
where usr.dept = 'SVC';
```